# Why is JSON returning only 1 image output for my query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I am executing a PHP script that encodes my query into JSON format, based on a database containing matches and teams. Match table has 2 fields

> (team_1 name and team_2 name as foreign keys)

while the Team table has the name of the team + logo.
This is my query to get the names of the teams playing and their logo in every match:

```
Select m.team_1, t1.team_logo, m.team_2, t2.team_logo
From Match m, Team t1, Team t2
Where t1.name = m.team_1 and t2.name = m.team_2;
```

My problem is that JSON is only returning the first team name, second team logo, and second team name.
Why is that? and how can I fix it?

Comment: You’ll have to show some code before anyone can say anything

Comment: Looks like the first `team_logo` is overwritten by the second because of the name clash.

Comment: @stickybit How can I solve this?

Comment: By using two different names.

Comment: @stickybit For the same team_logo field? Is that possible? Sorry for being a noob about this

Comment: Yes. Use alias for the columns in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select 
  m.team_1, t1.team_logo AS logo_team1, 
  m.team_2, t2.team_logo AS logo_team2
From Match m, Team t1, Team t2 
Where t1.name = m.team_1 and t2.name = m.team_2;
```

Regards